# How can we export pdf created in jspdf as an image?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I've created a pdf in my program using jspdf, I'm providing an option to download as image or as pdf, so Can I use jspdf in some way or the pdf I created using jspdf in someway to store it as image?

I

Comment: Did you find an answer?